# Forçar atualização de versão de arquivo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, front-end, angular

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em *Angular2* e estou enfrentando um problema que é a atualização dos arquivos *JS*. Quando atualizo a versão as vezes o navegador não carrega o novo arquivo, usa o antigo.
Eu sei que se colocar a versão do arquivo no final da referência, como:

`nomedoarquivo.js?v=1` funciona.

O problema é que em *Angular2* não é referenciado os arquivos *js* diretamente na *index.html* como no Angular JS 1, os arquivos *JS* são carregados através do *SystemJS*.
Alguém conhece uma forma de forçar ele a sempre carregar o *JS* novo, ou versionar o *JS* usando o *SystemJS*?

Comment: A resposta resolve seu problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que este problema no SystemJS é conhecido: encontrei um [issue em discussão no GitHub](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/172)

Neste Issue há um possível WorkAround: um plugin Gulp chamado systemjs-cachebuster. Se você estiver usando Gulp, talvez seja uma solução simples.

Sugiro também que você avalie o [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server). Quando testei o Angular2, fiz uso do lite-server e não lembro de ter me deparado com problemas com cache e, inclusive, o hot-reloading ajuda bastante com o ciclo de feedback.

Instalar o lite-server no seu projeto é simples usando o NPM:

```
npm install lite-server --save-dev
```

No seu package.json simplesmente ajuste o script "start" ou um de sua preferência.

```
"scripts": {
  "lite": "lite-server",  
},
```

Execute com um npm run:

```
npm run lite
```

Se você estiver utilizando TypeScript, simplesmente mantenha o compilador em --watch e o lite-server irá identificar novas versões dos arquivos Js.